# SQLAlchemy bindparam substitutes a NULL while another value is bound

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, null

I have the following expression

```
func.ST_Simplify(
  func.ST_Transform(column('route_segment'), 3857),
  bindparam('dist')/10
  True
),
```

which for some reason gets rendered into

```
ST_Simplify(ST_Transform(route_segment, 3857), NULL / 10, TRUE)
```

This seems wrong because when I set `dist` in `.params` and do a `.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})`, everywhere else it is rendered as the set value.

Why can this be happening?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? I guess the pieces in your post can be put together to possibly replicate your results, but it'll raise your odds of getting answers, if you remove that initial stepping stone by providing a pretty much "copy&paste" example in the question.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thank you for your suggestion. I have already found a solution, and will self-answer as soon as I can.